# Crash log not getting in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am not getting crash log in Debug area like below

Example of objective-c:

```
Problems[12540:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', 
reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]'
*** First throw call stack:
. . . and so on . . .
```

Like the above, In Swift i am not getting the reason of the crash.
I enabled NSZombies in Edit Sceheme and I set Optimization Level --> Debug to None.